# Is the light intensity from inverter type welders different from transformer type welders?

Tags: safety, welding

I have tried researching this, but cannot find any supporting information.

I would like to know if the light intensity from inverter type welders is different to transformer type welders, and if so, what is that difference. I can definitely feel the difference between the two when welding so there must be a difference in their light intensities.

My father, is old school and does not like inverter - his reasoning "it gives arc eyes". I did not believe him at the time, but through many years of trial and error, I do find that even the slightest flash on inverter results in arc eyes, it even got so bad at one stage that I was convinced I was getting flash through the helmet - as a result I added more glass and thicker shades.

I generally even use less amps on the inverter welder, so its definitely not more power = more flash. Could there be a difference in the two light outputs?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this myself and agree, yes, there is a difference in the light outputs between inverter and transformer type welders (even at the same amperage setting). I also have seen a difference between different models of inverter MIG welders.  I don't precisely know what makes the difference, but I am guessing it has to do with differences in the switching characteristics. Also, different types of welders have different output... e.g. a stick welder, IMHO, seems to have much more UV output (at least the ones I've used).  I can get a bit of a "sunburn" from only a couple of sticks if I don't make sure to cover up.  I've never had that happen for an equivalent amount of welding on a MIG.

But we need not rely on anecdotal evidence...  The link below is to a paper published by the German equivalent of OSHA, where they actually measure the light output from various welders at 180 Amps.

http://bit.ly/1zKakL1